# How to pass a linc to class function and call it?

Tags: c++, oop, boost

So I have a class like

```
class mySafeData
{
public:
    void Set( int i ) 
    {
        myMutex.lock();
        myData = i;
        myMutex.unlock();
    }
    void Get( int& i)
    {
        myMutex.lock();
        i = myData;
        myMutex.unlock();
    }
private:
    int myData;
    boost::mutex myMutex;

};
```

its instance is running. Lets call instance A. I want to create a new class that would take as a start up argument some kind of link to Getter from A and would be capable to somehow save link to thet getter for calling it inside its private methods vhen needed. how to do such thing?

Comment: The locking and unlocking of the mutex is *managing a resource manually*, something we don't do in C++. You should use SBRM (RAII) techniques, which Boost does, and do this instead: ``void Set(int i) { boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex); myData = i }`. Now the mutex, once locked, is guaranteed to be unlocked automatically *no matter what*. And it's cleaner in general. (Obviously do the same in `Get`. For something operating on int's, this isn't going to make a huge difference (just readability), but the statements between lock and unlock can throw exceptions, it's critical.

Comment: Also, is there a reason your `Get` function returns using a parameter? That's very unorthodox. I suspect it's because you didn't know how to `unlock` the mutex after you returned. If you do what I said in the above comment, like I said you can return just fine and the mute with unlock itself. You'll want to do that. :)

Comment: OK, I thought you might mean the `get` function when you said, "link to Getter in A," but then when you said you wanted to call into A's privates you totally lost me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
class myOtherData
{
public:
    myOtherData(mySafeData& dataSource) :
    myDataSource(&dataSource)
    {}

private:
    // note that if you take the advice in the comments,
    // you don't need this wrapper function at all,
    // it's simple just to call myDataSource.Get()
    int GetData()
    {
        int result;
        myDataSource.Get(result);

        return result;
    }

    mySafeData* myDataSource;
};

mySafeData a;
myOtherData b(a);

// b uses a as its data source (make sure it lives as long!)
```

Comment: "b uses a as its data source (make sure it lives as long" hm.. how do I kill A? - only after b? and how to kill such B and my A?

Comment: @Kabumbus: Well, if they were automatically (stack) allocated, like regular variables in a function, they go away at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by linc/link.  Are you asking for anything more than this pattern?

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(mySafeData& d) : data(d) {}

    int someFunction() {
        int i;
        data.get(i);
        return i;
    }
private:
    mySafeData& data;
};

...
Foo f(a);
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with pointers? Smart, Shared, Scoped... I'll use standard pointers for now.

```
class B
{
public:
  B(mySafeData* ptr) // constructor takes a memory pointer as parameter
  :SafeData_ptr(ptr)
  { 
     SafeData_ptr->foo(); // call public function from class A
  }

  ~B() // destructor
  {
  }

private:
  mySafeData* SafeData_ptr; // will hold the mem address of instance A when
                            // this class is initialized
};
```

Later on your code, when you have instance A ready, you would do something like this:

```
B b_demo(&A); // &A passes the memory address of the instantiated object
              // and A::foo() will be automatically called when B is constructed.
```

This is probably not the smartest way to do it, but I think it illustrates the idea.

Comment: Hm, ok I suppose, though I'd hope that's what a book would do. :)